# create random id without no childByAutoId firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, random, firebase-realtime-database

i what to create a random ID to an object in firebase, i know i can use childByAutoId, but is there any other way to create a random ID with firebase database.

I know it's possible to create a random number with arc4random() in swift and that works, but is there a better solution?

Comment: Sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why are `childByAutoId` and `arc4random` not suitable for your needs? Please describe what you're trying to accomplish, rather than how you're trying to accomplish it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this:

```
let uniqueID = "\(NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000)\(arc4random())"
```

That would give you the current unix time in milliseconds concatenated with a random number and guarantee a new unique ID every millisecond.

I think you can also get unix time directly from Firebase too.